# CSS in Dynamically generated angular component

Tags: css, angular, d3.js

I am having an Angular4  app in which I am generating some graphs using D3,
In my D3 code, I have added some classes on some element and the CSS file conations the style definition which will be applied to them. The fact is that CSS is never applied to those elements.

Comment: check the file path of your CSS and check you have included properly.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai path is proper, its something related to shadow-piercing

Answer (score 0):

You can use d3.style() property to add styles to certain elements you select in your DOM. It's a hard-coded solution but it works.

EDIT: As @GerardoFurtado pointed out, I made a typo error. I was referring to the

```
  selection.style()
```

property where you append styles to the selected element you're generating.
A simple implementation of this will be:

```
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
        .style("fill", "blue");
```

Comment: `d3.style()` is always a **getter**, never a setter. You're thinking about `selection.style()`, which is different.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado correct, didn't notice it (consider it as a typo)